# Symfony Functional Test on a controller with LoginFormAuthenticator

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have a Symfony4 app that is basically done and now am writing some tests for it.  I'm trying to see if I can get a success http 200 from this controller route using this command
  ***vendor/bin/phpunit  --debug  tests/SampleTest.php***

The page is protected by the default login form auth that symfony uses (debug below)

```
    /**
     * @IsGranted("ROLE_BRAND")
     * @Route("/user/dashboard", methods={"GET"}, name="user_index", condition="context.getHost() in ['mysite.test', 'www.mysite.test']")
     *
     */
    public function dashboard(Request $request ): Response {
             ...clipped....
    }
```

```
[2020-03-04 18:48:09] request.INFO: Matched route "user_index". {"route":"user_index","route_parameters":{"_route":"user_index","_controller":"App\\Controller\\Backend\\DashboardController::dashboard"},"request_uri":"https://mysite.test/user/dashboard","method":"GET"} []
[2020-03-04 18:48:10] security.DEBUG: Read existing security token from the session. {"key":"_security_main","token_class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Authentication\\Token\\UsernamePasswordToken"} []
[2020-03-04 18:48:10] security.DEBUG: Checking for guard authentication credentials. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticators":1} []
[2020-03-04 18:48:10] security.DEBUG: Checking support on guard authenticator. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginFormAuthenticator"} []
[2020-03-04 18:48:10] security.DEBUG: Guard authenticator does not support the request. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginFormAuthenticator"} []
[2020-03-04 18:48:10] security.DEBUG: Access denied, the user is neither anonymous, nor remember-me. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AccessDeniedException(code: 403): Access Denied. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\mysite\\vendor\\symfony\\security-http\\Firewall\\AccessListener.php:99)"} []
[2020-03-04 18:48:10] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException: "Access Denied." at C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\vendor\symfony\security-http\Firewall\ExceptionListener.php line 137 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\AccessDeniedHttpException(code: 0): Access Denied. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\mysite\\vendor\\symfony\\security-http\\Firewall\\ExceptionListener.php:137, Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AccessDeniedException(code: 403): Access Denied. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\mysite\\vendor\\symfony\\security-http\\Firewall\\AccessListener.php:99)"} []
```

This is the test code from https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/testing/http_authentication.html

```
namespace App\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

class SampleTest extends WebTestCase {
    private $client = null;

    public function setUp(): void {
        $this->client = static::createClient();
    }

    public function testSecuredHello() {
        $this->logIn();
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', 'https://mysite.test/user/dashboard');
        $this->assertSame(Response::HTTP_OK, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }

    private function logIn() {
        $session = self::$container->get('session');

        $firewallName = 'main';
        // if you don't define multiple connected firewalls, the context defaults to the firewall name
        // See https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context
        $firewallContext = 'main';

        // you may need to use a different token class depending on your application.
        // for example, when using Guard authentication you must instantiate PostAuthenticationGuardToken
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken('user@good.com', null, $firewallName, ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_BRAND']);
        $session->set('_security_' . $firewallContext, serialize($token));
        $session->save();

        $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
        $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
    }
}
```

bin/console debug:config security

```
Current configuration for extension with alias "security"
=========================================================

security:
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
                manager_name: null
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto
            migrate_from: {  }
            hash_algorithm: sha512
            key_length: 40
            ignore_case: false
            encode_as_base64: true
            iterations: 5000
            cost: null
            memory_cost: null
            time_cost: null
            threads: null
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:
            - ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH
            - ROLE_BRAND
            - ROLE_ADVOCATES_VISIBLE
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
            methods: {  }
            user_checker: security.user_checker
            stateless: false
            logout_on_user_change: true
        main:
            anonymous:
                lazy: false
                secret: null
            switch_user:
                parameter: _switch_to_brand_login
                role: ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH
                stateless: false
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
                entry_point: null
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                csrf_parameter: _csrf_token
                csrf_token_id: logout
                target: /
                invalidate_session: true
                delete_cookies: {  }
                handlers: {  }
            remember_me:
                remember_me_parameter: _remember_me
                secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
                lifetime: 604800
                path: /
                user_providers: {  }
                catch_exceptions: true
                name: REMEMBERME
                domain: null
                secure: null
                httponly: true
                samesite: lax
                always_remember_me: false
            methods: {  }
            security: true
            user_checker: security.user_checker
            stateless: false
            logout_on_user_change: true
    access_control:
        -
            path: ^/user/account
            roles:
                - IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY
            requires_channel: null
            host: null
            port: null
            ips: {  }
            methods: {  }
            allow_if: null
        -
            path: ^/user
            roles:
                - ROLE_USER
            requires_channel: null
            host: null
            port: null
            ips: {  }
            methods: {  }
            allow_if: null
        -
            path: ^/admin
            roles:
                - ROLE_ADMIN
            requires_channel: null
            host: null
            port: null
            ips: {  }
            methods: {  }
            allow_if: null
    access_decision_manager:
        strategy: affirmative
        allow_if_all_abstain: false
        allow_if_equal_granted_denied: true
    access_denied_url: null
    session_fixation_strategy: migrate
    hide_user_not_found: true
    always_authenticate_before_granting: false
    erase_credentials: true
```

Using a PostAuthenticationGuardToken didn't work either.   I'm all out of ideas

Comment: does that user actually exist on the test system (it has to)?

Comment: @Jakumi yes it works fine with the actual login page. But something in the LoginFormAuthenticator is rejecting the automated process.  I think it's in here but not 100:

`
    public function supports(Request $request) {
        return 'app_login' === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

`

Comment: @Jakumi

`

    public function getCredentials(Request $request) {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => mb_strtolower(trim($request->request->get('email'))),
            'password' => trim($request->request->get('password')),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];

        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['email']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }
`

Comment: hint: if the code is long enough to contain a line break, you shouldn't put it in comments.